# Pasar de milisegundos a un tiempo en horas, minutos y segundos en Java

Tags: java, postgresql, date, postgresql-9.3

Tengo una variable en un `String` y son los milisegundos que se tardan en llegar de un punto a otro. Necesito poner ese valor en formato Horas:Minutos:Segundos

Estoy usando Java 6 y objetos `Date`, pero cuando envío este valor a la base de datos, el resultado no es el esperado.:

```
String tiempo = "857"; // Es el tiempo en milisegundos
long duration = Long.parseLong(tiempo);
action.setDuration(new Time(duration));
```

Estoy usando una PostgreSQL 9.3 y el DDL donde se crea la tabla en la que almaceno el valor es

```
sug_duration time without time zone, -- Time duration
```

Me devuelve siempre 01:00:00, aunque el tiempo sea menor

¿Alguna idea que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12504608/4092887)

Comment: Estoy probando lo que me dices. Gracias!

Comment: No me vale la solución. Solamente me interesa la parte de las horas, minutos y segundos, no el día ni la fecha completa

Comment: ¿Qué valor tiene la variable `tiempo`? yo te recomiendo actualizar tu pregunta con el valor de la variable `tiempo`, además de primero, convertir `tiempo` a un DateTime; para obtener el tiempo entre dos fechas, por ejemplo, usa [interval](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581621/4092887). Espero que alguien con mas conocimientos en java que yo te pueda ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: Son milisegundos, por ejemplo 3139, 857, y valores así

Comment: [Sala de chat para ayudar a resolver el problema](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48274/discussion-between-sioesi-and-jjmartinez)

Answer (score 2):

Puedo hacer una función que convierta los milisegundos. Sé que 1000 milisegundos es 1 segundo, que 60 segundos es un minuto, que 60 minutos es una hora.

```
public static int milisegundos2tiempo(int ms)
{
    int mili = ms%1000; ms -= mili; ms /= 1000;
    int segs = ms%60; ms -= segs; ms /= 60;
    int mins = ms%60; ms -= mins; ms /= 60;
    int horas = ms;
    return horas*1000*100*100 + mins*1000*100 + segs*1000 + mili;
}
```

Te devolverá un entero medio extraño, no te preocupes, te lo explico:

Si te devuelve 223344555, significa que son 22 horas con 33 minutos con 44 segundos y 555 milisegundos... Esto puede devolver una cantidad de horas mayor a 24... En ese caso, solo hay que cambiar `int horas = ms;` por `int horas = ms%24;`... También es recomendable alguna función para convertir ese número extraño a un String y formatearlo con barras o guiones (/ o -).

Ya que necesitas devolver un `Date`, he decidido investigar, y encontré un [enlace](http://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=618:clase-date-del-api-java-metodos-before-after-tolocalestring-togmtstring-y-gettime-ejemplos-cu00924c&catid=58:curso-lenguaje-programacion-java-nivel-avanzado-i&Itemid=180) que explica eso. Editando un poco, tengo la respuesta que necesitas.

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Programa {
    public static void main (String []args){

        System.out.print ("Ingrese la cantidad de milisegundos:\n");
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.close();

        int res = milisegundos2tiempo(n);
        Date fecha1;
        fecha1 = new Date(100,0,0,res%10000000,res%100000,res%1000);
        System.out.println( fecha1.toGMTString() );
    }
}
```